# Optimize a heavy query with multiple joins and unions

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Are there any optimization tricks for this query to reduce the execution time, which is pretty long. Maybe converting the `UNION` to `JOIN` or using `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "TOTAL"
FROM
    ADS A
    JOIN USERS U ON U.ID = A.USERID
    JOIN LOGIN L ON L.USERID = U.ID
    JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM HOMES T
            UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM CHALETS T
            UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM COUNTRYHOUSES T
            UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM OFFICES T
            UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM BUILDINGS T
            UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM WAREHOUSES T
        ) T
        WHERE
            T.CERTIFICATIONID IN (NULL, 9, 10)
            OR (T.CERTIFICATIONID != 1 AND T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID IS NULL)
    ) CERT ON CERT.ADID = A.ID
WHERE U.USERTYPE = 1
```

Comment: Execute `alter session set statistics_level=all` then execute your query and provide results of `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('','','allstats last')) `

Comment: And what do you store in the table `login`?

Comment: Why have different tables for `HOMES`, `CHALETS`, `COUNTRYHOUSES`, `OFFICES`, BUILDINGS` and `WAREHOUSES`? Why not have a single `BUILDINGS` table and then an extra column that contains a flag for the building type and then you do not have to concatenate the rows from the tables.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov This is the output:
 
NOTE: cannot fetch plan for SQL_ID: 5rsm4y10jd4p2, CHILD_NUMBER: 1
      Please verify value of SQL_ID and CHILD_NUMBER; 
      It could also be that the plan is no longer in cursor cache (check v$sql_plan)

Comment: Using `UNION ALL` should be quicker than using `UNION` as the latter will have to deduplicate the result set.

Comment: @SGodoy what tool do you use for it? Try sqlplus with `set serverout off`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
with CERT as (
    SELECT--+ no_merge
       ADDID, count(*) cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM HOMES T
        UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM CHALETS T
        UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM COUNTRYHOUSES T
        UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM OFFICES T
        UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM BUILDINGS T
        UNION SELECT T.ADID, T.CERTIFICATIONID, T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID FROM WAREHOUSES T
    ) T
    WHERE T.CERTIFICATIONID != 1
    and (T.CERTIFICATIONID IN (9, 10) OR T.CERTIFICATIONEMISSIONSID IS NULL)
    group by ADDID
)
SELECT sum(cnt) AS "TOTAL"
FROM
    ADS A
    JOIN USERS U ON U.ID = A.USERID
    JOIN LOGIN L ON L.USERID = U.ID
    JOIN CERT  ON CERT.ADID = A.ID
WHERE U.USERTYPE = 1
```

Comment: Would be better if i replace each subselect with a join with the ADS table to avoid having a huge tem table?

Comment: use UNION ALL instead of UNION if possible for avoiding extra ODERING. For large data it's degrade performance.

Comment: @RahulBiswas first of all, check the OP's query: if you change UNION to UNION ALL, you will get different count, because of duplicates in CERT inline view. Secondly, we can't discuss about performance without exact real execution plans.

Comment: @SGodoy depends on your data... You need to learn how to get real execution plans with statistics.

Comment: Or real-time sql monitor report

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov that's why I've used "if possible" in my comment. Anyway thanks for reply. It's a good solution.